# MySQL limit "main" results when using left joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck at a simple MySQL query which I just can't wrap my head around (it's a bit late here). If this answer is easy to find I'm sorry, I've spent half an hour searching and want to get it over with.

I want to limit the results of the "main" query, the non-joined values, to 10.

```
SELECT
  i_item_id AS itemId,
  v_value_id AS valueId,
  v_value_title AS valueTitle
FROM items
LEFT JOIN items_values ON iv_item_id=i_item_id
LEFT JOIN values ON v_value_id=iv_value_id
LIMIT 10
```

However, since the values are about 4-5 for each item, the limit "fills up" by the valueIds, which leaves me with 2-3 items. How do I write the above query so that I get 10 items, and as many valueIds as necessary?

I've tried using a subquery in the SELECT fields, but I got an error regarding that the subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: It's early here, haven't had my tea, but possible hint: `SELECT .. FROM (SELECT .. LIMIT 10) as T LEFT JOIN ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you just be able to limit the results in a sub query and then execute the joins...
though I think you'd want to supply an order by to get the "Right" 10.

```
SELECT
  i_item_id AS itemId,
  v_value_id AS valueId,
  v_value_title AS valueTitle
FROM (Select * from items limit 10) items
LEFT JOIN items_values ON iv_item_id=i_item_id
LEFT JOIN values ON v_value_id=iv_value_id
```

Comment: Solved my problem in a very quick way, thank you! How about the performance? Also, should I narrow down the columns fetched from items instead of the *?

Comment: Yes, the select * was because I was unsure if you would add additional columns from items later.  I'm more concerned about the 10 that get returned from the subquery.  If you have an index on the field you order by, it should be very quick.

Comment: Added the ORDER BY at the end of the main query (not the one with the LIMIT) which works beautifully, and fast! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work. Basically you get 10 item ids and query results only for those ids.

However, you may want to add an `ORDER BY` clause or you will get random results.

```
SELECT 
    i_item_id AS itemId,
    v_value_id AS valueId,
    v_value_title AS valueTitle
FROM items
    LEFT JOIN items_values ON iv_item_id = i_item_id
    LEFT JOIN values ON v_value_id = iv_value_id
WHERE i_item_id IN (SELECT i_item_id
                    FROM items
                    LIMIT 10
                   )
```